# how to know if a GTK window is minimized in ruby

Tags: ruby, gtk3

i want to know if the window is minimized or not. i have connected `window-state-event` signal from GtkWidget to this function

```
    def on_main_window_hide(object, event)
      if event.changed_mask & Gdk::WindowState::ICONIFIED
        if event.new_window_state & Gdk::WindowState::ICONIFIED
          puts("minimize" + $counter.to_s)
          $counter+=1
        else
          puts ("unminimize")
        end
      end
    end
```

and even after doing minimizing and unminimizing couple of times .. it never prints if the window is unminimized, here is the output

```
    minimize0
    minimize1
    minimize2
    minimize3
    minimize4
```

plus, minimizing gives the window-state-event signal twice, like if `minimize0` is initial value then on minimizing it becomes `minimize2` 
how can i detect properly if a window is minimized ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you got confused by the callback name. The `window-state-event` signal gets emitted for every state event change, so the callback should be called `on_main_window_state_event` as it will be emitted not only when the window hides. Then you can check the event mask for changes.

Your callback has a redundant if condition. [From the API](https://developer.gnome.org/gdk3/stable/gdk3-Event-Structures.html#GdkEventWindowState), the `changed_mask` is a:

> mask specifying what flags have changed

And `window_new_state` is also a mask but contains:

> the new window state, a combination of GdkWindowState bits

This means that the second if condition will always evaluate as true if the first one also evaluates as true but the else branch will never happen. If you want your "unminimize" print to occur then you must remove the second if condition and move the print to the else branch of the first if condition. Another option would be to check for the bit mask and really check the status.

Your code should be:

```
def on_main_window_state_event(object, event)
  if event.changed_mask & Gdk::WindowState::ICONIFIED
    puts("minimize" + $counter.to_s)
    $counter+=1
  else
    puts ("unminimize")
  end
end
```